# ios swift method to navigate through viewcontroller programatically

Tags: swift, uiwindow

i would like create  my function to navigate through my views.

i have a function

```
   func ShowView(name:String,caller:AppDelegate){


        //story board
        let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)

        let initViewController: UIViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(name) as UIViewController

        caller.UIWindow?.rootViewController = initViewController

}
```

but i need to call this function from AppDelegate and UIViewController , how can i get uiwindow from  UIViewController , from AppDelegate is ok but i can't keep AppDelegate like caller parameter cause i would like that it work with  UIViewController.
I don't really know which i must use for my parameter.

many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to replace rootView Controller every time if you are moving from master to details views. Connect root view to details view using segue. Set a identifier to segue in your storyboard. Overide prepareForSegue in your viewController class.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
```

```
    if(segue.identifier == "showDetails")
    {
        var viewController=segue.destinationViewController as DetailsView
        //set data            
     }
```

}

Comment: accept
 

thank,

I have no button or navgationbar in my view to set a segue in my storyboard, i want load my new viewcontroller programatically.

maybe you know a way to add segue without add button or navigation bar .

best regards

Comment: it's ok , ihave find a way to add segue without button , i drag the plus after a right clik on my viewcontroller thank